# Identifying all columns included in composite PK throughout the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to identify all the columns which are part of PK (composite or non-composite) throughout all the tables in my database. How can I do that with a sql statement? Desired result set:

TABLE NAME | COLUMN NAME | DATA TYPE | CONSTRAINT |

Comment: Did you try to look into the sys.indexes table? PK have index_id 1 and columns can be mapped with other system tables.

Comment: @DavidSöderlund - No they don't - clustered indexes have index_id of 1. While most PKs are clustered in the wild, the two are separate concepts.

Comment: Right you are, I was too quick.

Answer (score 2):

in Sql Server exists a system view to show all constraints.

Try this:

```
select * from sys.key_constraints where type_desc = 'PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT'
```

Comment: This is only a half-answer. The OP wants to know how to get the column names in the constraints, not just the constraints themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select 
    t.name as [TABLE NAME],
    c.name as [COLUMN NAME],
    ty.name as [DATA TYPE],
    i.name as [CONSTRAINT]
from sys.index_columns ic
join sys.indexes i
    on ic.object_id = i.object_id
    and ic.index_id = i.index_id
join sys.columns c
    on ic.object_id = c.object_id
    and ic.column_id = c.column_id
join sys.tables t
    on ic.object_id = t.object_id
join sys.types ty
    on c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
where i.is_primary_key = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied this into my snippets folder long ago, so I can't take credit for it, but this works well...

```
select s.name as TABLE_SCHEMA, t.name as TABLE_NAME, k.name as CONSTRAINT_NAME, c.name as COLUMN_NAME, ic.key_ordinal AS ORDINAL_POSITION
  from sys.key_constraints as k
  join sys.tables as t
    on t.object_id = k.parent_object_id
  join sys.schemas as s
    on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
  join sys.index_columns as ic
    on ic.object_id = t.object_id
   and ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id
  join sys.columns as c
    on c.object_id = t.object_id
   and c.column_id = ic.column_id
 where k.type = 'PK';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.name AS TableName, c.Name AS ColumnName, t.name AS DataType, kc.name AS ContraintName
FROM sys.key_constraints kc 
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON kc.parent_object_id = ic.object_id AND kc.unique_index_id = ic.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON ic.column_id = c.column_id AND c.object_id = ic.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON ic.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE kc.type = 'PK'
ORDER BY TableName,ic.key_ordinal
```